# VirtualBox 4.3.12 GuestAdditions not running

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

Trying to spin up VirtualBox 4.3.12 using vagrant 1.7.The GuestAdditions are installed correctly and vagrant-vbguest plugin is installed.However, the GuesAdditions arent running due to which vboxsf seems to be missing.Using VM 4.3.12 as this works well in compatibility with vagrant and higher version boxes were giving memory errors.

```
 GuestAdditions seems to be installed (4.3.12) correctly, but not running.
 stdin: is not a tty
 Usage: service < option > | --status-all | [ service_name [ command | --     full-restart ] ]
 bash: line 3: vboxadd: command not found
 stdin: is not a tty
 Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
 Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
 Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules
 The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following
 module compilation fails then this could be the reason.

Building the main Guest Additions module ...done.
Building the shared folder support module ...fail!
(Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong)
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
Guest Additions will not load, even after reboot.
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
default: /app => C:/myapp
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` app /app
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` app /app

The error output from the last command was:
stdin: is not a tty
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device
```

Any pointers to correct this will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest/issues/95) helped me diagnose the problem.

To sum up, you need to symlink the proper file to `/sbin/vboxadd`.  The solution suggested in the above issue was:

```
sudo ln -s /sbin/rcvboxadd /sbin/vboxadd
```

but that didn't work for me because the `/sbin/rcvboxadd` file also did not exist.  To find the version on my machine, I did:

```
locate vboxadd
```

and ended up using:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.18/init/vboxadd /sbin
```

This successfully gets rid of the `vboxadd: command not found` error.  It still leaves the `Usage: service` option, but I can't find any missing functionality resulting from that, so I'm currently just ignoring it.

Answer (score 1):

I constantly ran into GuestAddition issues. The following two steps have always worked for me:

1. On the VM:
   sudo yum update
2. shutdown the VM and add `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` in the storage settings of the VM, as a optical device.

`VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` can be found at:
Applications -> VirtualBox.app (right click, show content) -> Contents -> MacOS -> VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
You can copy it to some place for easy access.

Answer (score 0):

Which vagrant box are you trying to use?

I am using Vagrant 1.7.3 with VirtualBox 4.3.30. When we attempted VirtualBox 5.x, things broke. The GuestAdditions did seem to be included, but it was not straight forward trying to figure that out.

Comment: Using Vagrant 1.7.4 with 4.3.12 Virtual box.As you mentioned , VirtualBox 5.0.x and even 4.3.28,4.3.30 it broke stating memory error issue.

Answer (score 0):

I try 2 h for install 
   VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso 
for work with shared folders

1.
   I installed new: virtualbox-5.1.22-115126-win.exe

in menu - machine - settings - storage - controller IDE:
       create a empty Disk IDE

2. I installed from chip.de:
    http://search.chip.de/?q=VirtualBox-Extension-Pack&it=1

   Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.22-115126

   with chip installer download , you have to uncheck the addon software during setup , then download

   Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.22-115126.vbox-extpack

   in {Program}\VirtualBox   folder.

   OR
   , with manual setup download you get in RAR the file without the extension:

   Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.22-115126

   so copy in 
    {Program}\VirtualBox   folder and add the extension:

   Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.22-115126.vbox-extpack

   whenn VirtualBox is installed click on

   {Program}\VirtualBox\Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.22-115126.vbox-extpack

   that works for me